# How I close this hint on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio

[Hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuMg8.png)

Hi,

When I writing a program, studio code give me a hint like this. How can I close it?

Comment: Just press ESC.

Comment: Other way to disabled the suggestion from vsCode. Click File > Preferences > Settings.
Now expand "Text Editor"
Click on "Suggestions"
Click "Edit in Settings. json"